Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: [] on Contract Insert
I am getting this error while I run the Test Classes trying to validate a Change Set between Sandbox and Prod. The error is pointing to the line where I Insert a Contract with an AccountId related to an Account that I created in the test class.
Needlessly to say that this is not happening in Sandbox..
Please don't link any thread similar to this, I already read it all and no one of them helped.
I am sure that I'm missing some settings in production Org, but i really don't know what to change.
    Account acc2 = new Account();

    acc2.Name='test';
    acc2.Email__c='test@test.com';
    acc2.Phone='345987789';
    insert acc2;

    Contract c = new Contract();
   
    c.AccountId=acc2.id;
    insert c;


Please share your test class code otherwise we won't be able to see what's wrong

Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to learn about [ask] and take our quick [tour]. We'll be happy to help you, but we are going to need more information. Please [edit] your question to include any relevant code. The more code we can see, the better we'll be able to help you.

Edited with the part of code that is failing

Are you sure that acc2.Id is populated? If it's blank it won't work.

I am sure, the code is working great in sandbox, is while i validate the changeset that it gives me error

EDIT: For anyone that might encounter this problem, for some reason i had to set the field Status on contract and i resolved the issue
